# how to make sure that exported Eclipse RCP application works in MAC.

Tags: eclipse-rcp

1) created simple hello world eclipse app.
2) product configuration created.
3)In overview tab of product Configuration clicked on "Eclipse Product Export Wizard"
4)Destination chosen as Archive file and stored in local system.
5)extracted the zip folder and if i click on icon it is successfully showing the exported result.
6)But if I copy the zip folder in mac and if i extract and try to click on the .exe it is not showing the proper result instead it was showing Archive window.

I would like to know what steps should follow so that exported Eclipse RCP application(which built on windows) works in mac.

quicker response would help me to fix my issue.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RCP builds are specific to a single operating system (Mac, Linux, Windows), GUI system (Cocoa, GTK, Windows) and architecture (64 bit, 32 bit). You will have to build separate Mac and Windows builds.

To build for multiple platforms you have to set up a target platform which includes the Mac specific code (and any other platforms you want). Using a target platform based on one of the Eclipse software sites will give you this.

Once you have done this the Export wizard will let you export for multiple platforms and lets you choose which platforms to export for.

Comment: Thanks greg..for solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have done below steps to solve this issue

1)window+preference+TargetPlatform+select running platform +click on Edit.
2)then popup will open + click on add +click on istallation/software site+provide delta pack path.
3)so that when ever we trying to export RCP product from "Export product configuration" in product file we can observer the multiple platforms oprion in that dialog box.